# DataTables json is not processed (in Laravel)

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

Datatables does nothing with the json it requested

I am using Yajra's Datatables to populate my table and I did everything by the book. The controller is set up correctly, the routes are good (if I enter the route designated to the controller function which creates the Database, I can see the desired json in the desired format:

```
{"draw":0,
 "recordsTotal":44,
 "recordsFiltered":44,
 "data":[{
          "agency":"agency",
          "number":"20966512",
          "name":"Name John",
          "value":"28.22",
        }]
}
```

This is the .js code that I use to create my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tbl').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route("datatable") !!}',
    columns: [
        {data: 'agency', name: 'agency'},
        {data: 'number', name: 'number'},
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
        {data: 'value', name: 'value'},
    ]
  });
});
```

I am getting an error stating:

> DataTables warning: table id=tbl - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

When I look in the console I get the following error:

```
{
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file": "/home/vagrant/Projects/Uniqa-ACB/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
"line": 179,
"trace": etc...
}
```

Laravel 5.8,
PHP 7.3,
Yajra DT: 6,
datatables.net: 1.10

Thank you in advance, if you need any more code I wil gladly input it.

Comment: So, `NotFoundHttpException` - something's not found on your backend. Show you controller method or something where do you process data.

Comment: @Tarasovych `NotFoundHttpException` means Laravel failed to match any route for a request. He needs to look at his routes file and URL that was requested via ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route that was trying to access contained the full json with some weird encoding on it, I changed the route to "/datatables" directly and as recommended bellow, I also specified the post type to GET, and now the tables are being populated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

replace ajax with this

```js
ajax: {
    "url": "{!! route("datatable") !!}",
    "type": "POST",
  }
```

Comment: I replaced it, but without the quotes on URL and TYPE, and I made it a GET type. I also changed the URL to simply "/datatable" and now my tables are populated! I can't believe it worked! But why did it work though ?

Comment: i think you are not defined route name in web.php so this error is occurred means Route::get('/datatable', 'AdminController@datatable')->name('datatable'); here name is your route name. so it works properly. you have not defined name then you can use url means "{{ url('/datatable) }}"

Comment: @NicuZamfir if you got your answer then please mark this as accepted answer.so it will not populate in unanswered questions